# Kerberos Authentication for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, kerberos

I am still seeing the following exception while trying to access SQL Server using Kerberos. What am I missing?

```
Connecting to jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:PORT;databaseName=DB_NAME;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;applicationName=GAA-MFI-Switches; using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver = USER
Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:4d83d195-c50c-404e-8bb0-39d90d1b9fda
```

Some notes:

1. I created my keytab file KEY_TAB.keytab
2. Confirmed that my user has permission to access the database through SSMS
3. Initialized the krb cache like this:
       kinit -k -t KEY_TAB.keytab USER@DOMAIN.COM
4. Ran 'klist" and verified that I can see my principal there:

   ```
   >klist
   Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_cdc104145_9Z6n4S
   Default principal: USER@DOMAIN.COM

   Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
   12/01/2017 14:19:10  12/02/2017 00:19:10  krbtgt/COMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
       renew until 12/08/2017 14:19:10
   12/01/2017 14:19:38  12/02/2017 00:19:10  MSSQLSvc/[PLACEHOLDER].com:1433@DOMAIN.COM
       renew until 12/08/2017 14:19:10
   12/01/2017 14:19:48  12/02/2017 00:19:10  HTTP/[PLACEHOLDER].com@DOMAIN.COM
       renew until 12/08/2017 14:19:10
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please describe your architecture in more detail.  Not nearly enough details to answer this.

Comment: Where did you run that klist command, on the client or on server? Are client, server and KDC on different servers? Is SQL service running under Local System account or a domain account? If domain account, had you recently changed it from local account to domain account? Is the SQL server running on the same server which has the keytab, or on a different server?